# Is there a custom to color eggs on Lag Baomer?

Tags: minhag, ashkenazi, eggs, lag-ba-omer

I heard from an old Lithuanian/Polish Jew (frum from Lithuania/Poland). He says that he had a custom to eat colored eggs in his shtetl, and everyone did it.

Is this custom documented anywhere, and does anyone mention it?

Comment: @HahuGavra http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/241/Q3/

Comment: @AmHaaretzGamurMideoraysa theres an article about it [here](http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/241/Q3/), although they fail to trace it to any written source, which seems to be what youre looking for.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22977

Comment: sounds christian to me. i'm close with chabad and i never heard of it.

Comment: I only know this from family friends so take this with a grain of salt - In ex-soviet countries a lot of Jews had a lot of different costumes. For example they would eat Kosher and celebrate Hanukkah but also celebrate Novigod which is a non-religious but very close to Christmas holiday.

Comment: @Bracha did you mean to post that comment on the answer that mentions Chabad?  The question doesn't.

Comment: So this is where the non-Jews get the custom to color eggs for Easter...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Despite it's apparent similarity to pagan practices dating back thousands of years, this custom exists in some communities ([particularly among Lubavitchers and some other Chassidic groups](http://people.ucalgary.ca/~elsegal/Shokel/000420_PassoverEgg.html)) and dates back at least several decades. Similar customs (such as eating colored eggs on Purim) existed in Jewish communities in [Afghanistan](http://people.ucalgary.ca/~elsegal/Shokel/000420_PassoverEgg.html) and [Yemen](http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/241/Q3/), and [women in Tunisia would write messages on eggs for Lag Ba'omer](http://www.jimena.org/saal.html). These customs date back at least several decades, too.

The customs of these various *kehillos* may share a common origin, but how much farther back these various customs extend may be a matter of speculation. Interestingly, the earliest known pagan custom originated in Persia around the time of Purim, and may therefore have been adapted from a Jewish custom for Purim.

Comment: +1. Re "women in Tunisia would write messages on eggs for Lag Ba'omer": note that that's a chasidic custom for _upshern_ also. I wonder whether the two bear a common origin (especially inasmuch as many _upshernishen_ (is that the plural?) are on _lag baomer_).

Comment: Minhag Chabad is to color eggs brown during the cooking process: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30483&st=&pgnum=290

Comment: @Curiouser: In the fine print he says that this is Minhag Karlin as well. He doesn't bring it there, but the eggs are browned by cooking them with onion peels.

Comment: @Curiouser: I don't know that I'd call that official Minhag Chabad, though. It may just have been the Rebbe's personal custom.