# Decorating of the Beitzah

Tags: minhag, passover, avodah-zarah, eggs, hukot-hagoyim

Somebody told me in Israel some have the custom of decorating the egg for Pesach (like an Easter egg). Wouldn't that be considered chukas hagoyim or avoda zara?

Comment: LC128, thanks fr the interesting question, which would be bettered by the inclusion of indication why you think it would be _chukas hagoyim_ or _a"z_. Welcome to the site. I hope you stick around nd enjoy it.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16162/is-there-a-custom-to-color-eggs-on-lag-baomer

Comment: I have never heard of this practice. What communities do this? When did it begin? Is it a conscious imitation of Easter eggs? Or did it possibly arise in communities that are unaware of Easter eggs?

Comment: According to some quick research on wikipedia dyeing the eggs red is a practice with religious symbolism. But anything else is just artwork, and you can't say that Jews are not allowed to do artwork just because goyim to it too.

Comment: I remember years ago seeing a Mordechai which mentions a minhag to write psukim on eggs to commemorate some type of celebration.

Answer (score 4):

Well, as [Fred's excellent answer over at the other question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16165/603) demonstrates, it is fairly well-established that several different Jewish communities had a custom to dye or colour eggs for various holidays, including Purim, Pesah, and Lag baOmer, in both the Mizrahi world ([Yemen](http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/241/Q3/), [Afghanistan and Kurdistan](http://people.ucalgary.ca/~elsegal/Shokel/000420_PassoverEgg.html)) and the Ashkenazi world ([Hassidic](http://people.ucalgary.ca/~elsegal/Shokel/000420_PassoverEgg.html) and [shtetl](http://books.google.ca/books?id=tGfYAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA12&dq=color%20eggs) customs). I've seen mentions in my reading to decorated eggs used in wedding ceremonies as well in [the Afghani community](http://books.google.ca/books?id=wVMwAAAAYAAJ&q=dyed%20eggs), and [this](http://books.google.ca/books?id=lnfRYwleeOkC&q=dyed%20eggs) suggests that it was part of Temani weddings as well.

As well, Segal mentions a related custom in the Polish world known as *gein af vikup*, which refers to visiting one's relatives and neighbours to receive coloured eggs: read (tantalizing hints) more [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=FfYUAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA123&dq=colored%20eggs) and [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=xVI-AAAAIAAJ&q=vikup%20eggs). I've always been curious myself about the relationship between these eggs and the traditional Eastern European tradition of [pysanky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pysanka), which are extraordinarily beautiful decorated eggs, with folk patterns that predate Christianity by many centuries. My friend has taught me the basics of pysanky-making, with which I have made several fairly-successful Pesah-themed eggs for our seder table. I like to think of that as entirely in keeping with the traditions of my Ashkenazi ancestors as well as my broader sense of Jewish heritage.

Comment: How does this answer whether the custom is forbidden or not?

Comment: Well, my point was that it's an established tradition in numerous Jewish communities, so clearly they didn't see it as forbidden! I generally assume that my ancestors knew more about their Judaism than I do, and it bothers me when people today go around making up humras and invalidating traditional Jewish practices. Furthermore, it's somewhat of a futile exercise: pretty much everything people think of as "Jewish" ritual or ceremony is in dialogue with (I don't like the phrase "borrowed from") the non-Jewish milieu in which it arose. So it's not "whether" but HOW it's Jewish, to me.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the specifics; such as who has such a practice, for how long, an if there are any sources, then I'm not certain we can presume that such a practice hasn't been consciously adopted the non-Jewish custom.  Either way it seems extremely problematic to maintain such a custom:

> It is the opinion of the Chochmas Adam 89:1 that when non-Jews establish a practice in the service of their religion then it is forbidden due to *Chukkas HaGoy* [non-Jewish practices] even if it is mentioned in the Torah that Jews had a similar practice (It would seem obvious that this doesn't apply to that which Jews are obligated to preform, I think our practice to avoid prostrating may be an example of this). If it is done by the non-Jews for no "good" reason then if it is mentioned in the Torah that Jews did so then they may continue so, but otherwise it is forbidden due to *Chukkas HaGoy*. The example given is there was once a practice to decorate Shuls with trees on *Hag* *HaShavuos* but the Gra nullified the practice because of *Chukkas HaGoy*. I suspect that *l'maaseh* it might not be as clear cut, but it seems like a very reasonable distinction to apply when faced with an issue. I would be interested if seen how other *poskim* address this question. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1407/899